# Start in a new thread in the same method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm beginner in the usage of threads and in the examples that I've seen (as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) a new thread must be assigned to a method. But, is there a way of making that inside the method? I'm looking for something like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
//Start new thread that affects only this method

//Do stuff
//More stuff

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes with a lambda or an anonymous delegate. What do you mean "...it affects only thus method..."?

Comment: what you  mean by affects  this method  only

Comment: I mean that actions performed inside that method are done in a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start anonymous method or lambda if you don't want to create separate method.

Simplest way:

```
Task.Run(()=>{
  // Your new thread code
});
```

Be aware that this creates closure and parent method variables you use in your thread will not be disposed until your thread is done. Also it's not a good practice to start a long running threads like this, because it uses thread pool.

So in this case you can do something like in the code below, or use more verbose syntax for creating tasks and specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` parameter.

```
new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate() {
 // Your new thread code
}).Start();
```

You can put new `Thread` object into variable to control it later.